# Jquery validate plugin not working for addmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery validate plugin. While trying to use mobile number regular expression validation it is not working. Could anyone help me on that.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod(
      "regex",
      function(value, element, regexp) {
          var check = false;
          var re = new RegExp(regexp);
          return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
      },""
);
});


            $("#membership_form").validate({
            rules: {
                "data[mobile]": {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    regex: '/^\2547\d{8}/'                                   
                },
            },
            messages: {
                "data[mobile]": {
                    required: 'Phone number is required',
                    regex:'Please match the pattern'
                },
            },


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The only suspect I see is the name in validate method. It seems you are trying to validate with wrong name as `data[mobile]`.

```js
$.validator.addMethod( "regex", function(value, element, regexp) { var check = false; var re = new RegExp(regexp); return this.optional(element) || re.test(value); },""); 

 $("#membership_form").validate({
            rules: {
                "Mobile": {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    regex: '/^\2547\d{8}/'                                   
                },
            },
            messages: {
                "Mobile": {
                    required: 'Phone number is required',
                    regex:'Please match the pattern'
                },
            }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="membership_form">
<input name="Mobile" type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Still this is not working. I think the issue is in regular expression. Could you please suggest.

Comment: what is not working? only regular expression? what do you want to validate with mobile number?